# How to introspect on PEP 484 type hints?

Tags: python-3.x, strong-typing

I have observed that for the following function

```py
def foo(x: int) -> List[int]:
   return x + 1
```

it is possible to obtain the annotation information using the expression `foo.__annotations__`, which yields `{'x': <class 'int'>, 'return': typing.List[int]}`.

Is this an official API? If not, does there exist an official API to obtain the signature for an object, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed part of the official API.

For functions you may also see [`inspect.signature()`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)