# python : using type hints to dynamically check types

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, duck-typing

python supports type hints:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

I was wondering if these hints can also be used to dynamically enforce types during runtime.

For example:

```py
class C:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a : int = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls,**kwargs):
        c = cls()
        for k,v  in kwargs.items():
            setattr(c,k,v) 
            # ValueError exception thrown here ?
        return c

attrs = {"a":"a"} # developer wanted an int !
c = C.get(**attrs)
print(c)
```

In short, I'd like to avoid to re-enter the type of the attribute "a" in the get function:

```py
    @classmethod
    def get(cls,**kwargs):
        c = cls()
        for k,v  in kwargs.items():
            if k=="a" and not isinstance(v,int):
                raise ValueError()
            setattr(c,k,v) 
        return c
```

Would there be a way to "reuse" the information given in the constructor that "a" is expected to be an int ?

Note: answer to this question shows that at least for functions introspection on the arguments type hints can be accessed:

[How to introspect on PEP 484 type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225507/how-to-introspect-on-pep-484-type-hints)

Comment: No runtime enforcement. The clue is in the term *hint*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if these hints can also be used to dynamically enforce types during runtime.

In some cases and with external lib - the answer is yes. Read below.

If the actual use-case you have is simple like your `C` class I would go and use dataclass and a library like dacite. You will not be able to create c2 since you are not passing an int.
So dacite managed to "see" that `a` should be int and raised an exception

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict
@dataclass
class C:
  a:int = 0

d1 = {'a':3}

c1: C = from_dict(C,d1)
print(c1)
print(C.__annotations__)

d2 = {'a':'3'}

c2: C = from_dict(C,d2)
```

output

```
C(a=3)
{'a': <class 'int'>}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    c2: C = from_dict(C,d2)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dacite/core.py", line 68, in from_dict
    raise WrongTypeError(field_path=field.name, field_type=field.type, value=value)
dacite.exceptions.WrongTypeError: wrong value type for field "a" - should be "int" instead of value "3" of type "str"
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing dataclasses and dacit. Before I tick it as the correct answer, may I ask you to edit by adding that ```C.__annotations__``` provides introspection to the types of the attributes of the class C ?

Comment: @Vince - Why do you want me do that? What is the added value here? The actail metadata is coming from "fields" (in the case of dacite) -- https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite/blob/a7834ba2421f6c52be8cd0f787660940deb9fc5b/dacite/dataclasses.py#L31

Comment: Anyway .. I have added it to the post. -- `print(C.__annotations__)`